# iterating over multindex - a groupby.value_counts() object is only through values and not through original date index

Tags: loops, indexing, group-by, multi-index

i want to know the percent of males in the ER (emergency room) during days that i defined as over crowded days.

i have a DF named eda with rows repesenting each entry to the ER. a certain column states if the entry occurred in an over crowded day (1 means over crowded) and a certain column states the gender of the person who entered.

so far i managed to get a series of over crowded days as index and a sub-index representing gender and the number of entries in that gender.

i used this code :

```
eda[eda.over_crowd==1].groupby(eda[eda.over_crowd==1].index.date).gender.value_counts()
```

and got the following result:
[image: image of my resulting grouper series]

my question is, what is the most 'pandas-ian' way to get the percent of males\females in general. or, how to continue from the point i stopped?

as can be shown in the bottom of the screenshot, when i iterate over the elements, each value is the male of female consecutively. i want to iterate over dates so i could somehow write a more clean loop that will produce another column of male percentage.

Answer (score 0):

i found a pretty elegant solution. i'm sure there are more, but maybe it can help someone else.

so i defined a multi-index series with all dates and counts of females and males. then used .loc to operate on each count of all dates to get percentage of males at each day. finally i just extract only the days that apply for over_crowd==1.

```
temp=eda.groupby(eda.index.date).gender.value_counts()
crowding['male_percent']=np.divide(100*temp.loc[:,1],temp.loc[:,2]+temp.loc[:,1])
crowding.male_percent[crowding.over_crowd==1]
```